Generate aar with obfuscated enabled makes different output for kotlin 1.7.20 vs 1.8.20
I would like to understand why the following situation is happening.
let's say I have the following interface in a library called Library A
Library A
interface FeatureFlag {
    var isFeatureEnabled: Boolean
}

Then, after compiling my library A (using obfuscated enabled) and upload the aar ( Or include generate the aar locally), I can consume for my application project.
Application compiled with kotlin 1.7.20
class FeatureManager: FeatureFlag {
    override var isFeatureEnabled = false
}

Application compiled with kotlin 1.8.20
class FeatureManager: FeatureFlag {
    
    override setFeatureFlagEnabled(isEnabled: Boolean) {
       
    }

    override getFeatureFlagEnabled(): Boolean {
  
    }
}

I would like to understand why this difference appearing between these two versions. Was there a change in the compiler that now is making the changes on the interface.
Also I noticed the following.
Library A
interface ApiContract{
    suspend fun call(code: String) Result<Something>
}

Application compiled with kotlin 1.7.20
class DefaultApiContract: ApiContract{
    override suspend fun call(code: String) :Result<Something>{
   
    }
}

Application compiled with kotlin 1.8.20
As you can see, after compiling the code. It added continuation parameter. I know this is generated when you used suspend function. But why it is different in kotlin 1.8.20 since in kotlin 1.7.20 it is respecting the contract
class DefaultApiContract: ApiContract{
    override suspend fun call(code: String, continuation: Continuation<Result<Any>>) : Any?{
   
    }
}

I tried using different things

Flags like kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs
Adding jvmAnotations
Adding proguard rules for interface ( Seems not to be working) Maybe I am declaring interface rules in pro guard wrong.
Upgrade gradle plugins

